# FFMPEG watermark + hls multi stream

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, hls

i want to convert mp4 video into hls multi resolution (360 , 720) and add watermark image inside the output segments

**i did two result but missing the watermark image with the multi scale**

```
//one hls with water mark image
ffmpeg \
-i input.mp4 \
-i watermark.png \
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=10:10:format=auto,format=yuv420p" \
-c:a copy -b:a 128k -c:v libx264 -crf 23 \
-f hls \
-hls_time 3 \
-hls_flags independent_segments \
-master_pl_name "output.m3u8" "output-%v.m3u8"


//multi hls with watermark text
ffmpeg \
-i ../input.mp4 \
-map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 \
-c:v:0 libx264 -crf 28 -preset faster -maxrate:v:0 600k -vf "drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:text='Your Watermark Text':x=10:y=10:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white, scale=-1:360"  -b:a:0 64k \
-c:v:1 libx264 -crf 28 -preset faster -maxrate:v:0 3000k -vf "drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:text='Your Watermark Text':x=10:y=10:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white, scale=-1:720" -b:a:0 64k \
-var_stream_map "v:0,a:0,name:360p v:1,a:1,name:460p" \
-f hls \
-hls_list_size 0 \
-threads 0 \
-hls_playlist_type event \
-hls_time 3 \
-hls_key_info_file ../keys/enc.keyinfo \
-hls_flags independent_segments \
-master_pl_name "output.m3u8" "output-%v.m3u8"
```